# exporting files from GCE to my local machine

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcutil

Is there a reverse command for `gcutil push` basically what I want to do is have a copy of my python files on my local machine so I'm looking for a way to import the files into my local machine exporting them from my google compute engine instance without using GIT or any other source control tool

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep, there is gcutil pull.  Here is the help file:

```
Local:~ mark$ gcutil help pull

Command line tool for interacting with Google Compute Engine.

Please refer to http://developers.google.com/compute/docs/gcutil/tips for more
information about gcutil usage.


USAGE: gcutil [--global_flags] <command> [--command_flags] [args]


pull                         Pull one or more files from a VM instance.

                         Usage: gcutil [--global_flags] pull
                         [--command_flags] <instance-name> <file-1> ...
                         <file-n> <destination>

                         Flags for pull:

gcutil_lib.instance_cmds:
  --ssh_arg: Additional arguments to pass to ssh;
repeat this option to specify a list of values
(default: '[]')
  --ssh_key_push_wait_time: Number of seconds to wait for updates to
project-wide ssh keys to cascade to the instances within the project
(default: '120')
(an integer)
  --ssh_port: TCP port to connect to
(default: '22')
(an integer)
  --zone: [Required] The zone for this request.

gflags:
--flagfile: Insert flag definitions from the given file into the command line.
(default: '')
--undefok: comma-separated list of flag names that it is okay to specify on
the command line even if the program does not define a flag with that name.
IMPORTANT: flags in this list that have arguments MUST use the --flag=value
format.
(default: '')


Run 'gcutil --help' to get help for global flags.
Run 'gcutil help' to see the list of available commands.
```

Answer (score 1):

The Syntax of file **uploading** to GCE from your Local Machine as following

gcutil push --zone=us-central1-a \
    my_instance \
~/local/path 
    /remote/file1 \
    /remote/file2 \

for example in mac

example

```
gcutil push --zone=us-central1-a \your-instance\  ~/Desktop/Gcloud /home/munish/
```

The Syntax of file **downloading** from GCE to your Local Machine as following

gcutil pull --zone=us-central1-a \
    my_instance \
    /remote/file1 \
    /remote/file2 \
    ~/local/path

for example in mac

example

```
gcutil pull --zone=us-central1-a \your-instance \ /home/munish/source-folder ~/Desktop/destination-folder
```